# Get list of subset from infinite generator in Python

Tags: python, generator, enumerate

**Summary**: I'm trying to learn about **itertools.islice**.

---

I'm trying to find the best way to get a list made up of a subset of the returns from an infinite generator function.  For example, I could want a list of the 1000th through 2000th item from a generator.

This is my example generator:

```
def infinite_counter():
    i = 0
    while True:
        i += 2
        yield i
```

These values are the return index from the generator that I want the list to start and stop:

```
start = 1000
end = 2000
```

**Method 1**: list comprehension **(fails)**

```
[val for ind,val in enumerate(infinite_counter()) if start <= ind <= end ]
```

This will quite obviously never return, when you expand into this:

```
for ind, val in enumerate(infinite_counter()):
    if start < ind < end:
       val
```

**Method 2**: list() **(works)**

```
list(next(iter([])) if ind > end else val for ind,val in enumerate(infinite_counter()) if ind >= start)
```

This works, but really feels like a hack.  It is also quite hard to follow, however I mistakenly thought it would be faster than Method 3.

**Method 3**: easy method **(works)**

```
my_list = []
for ind,val in enumerate(infinite_counter()):
    if ind >= start:
        my_list.append(val)
        if ind >= end:
            break
```

This is the first way I would think of doing this, before I chided my self from not being pythonic.  I was surprised that this was almost exactly the same as Method 2 in timing.

**Method 4**: itertools.takewhile **(works)**

```
[val for ind,val in itertools.takewhile(lambda tup: tup[0] < end, enumerate(infinite_counter())) if ind > start]
```

At first, I thought takewhile didn't work as I had the lambda as "lambda ind,val:".  But it gives the lambda a tuple of the two values.  I just need to take the first term in the tuple as the index for early exit.  This is slower than Method 2 and 3, and almost as slow as Method 5.

**Method 5**: wrapping generator **(works)**

```
def top_ending_generator(end):
    for ind,val in enumerate(infinite_counter()):
        if ind > end:
            break
        yield ind,val

[val for ind,val in top_ending_generator(end) if ind > start]
```

This is, as expected, considerably slower than methods 2 and 3.

Overall, I was surprised to see timing of Method 3 to be very close to timing of Method 2.  It is more code, but much easier for someone to follow.  This is currently how i have this implemented

Are there any other methods that I should consider or better solutions for this?

Edit:

**Method 6** itertools.islice **(the winner)**

```
list(itertools.islice(infinite_counter(), start, end))
```

This is slightly faster than my initial itertools.islice solution with list comprehension:

```
[val for val in itertools.islice(infinite_counter(), start_ind, end_ind)]
```

Amazing what finding the right method does.

For those keeping score, my timing found the following:

Method 6 = unit time

Method 2 ~= 2.5 * unit time

Method 3 ~= 3 * unit time

Method 4 ~= 4.2 * unit time

Method 5 ~= 4 * unit time

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
from itertools import islice

list(islice(infinite_counter(), 1000, 2000))
```

---

Note that this

```
list(next(iter([])) if ind > end else val for ind,val in enumerate(infinite_counter()) if ind >= start)
```

transforms to this

```
def _secret():
    for ind, val in enumerate(infinite_counter()):
        if ind >= start:
            if ind > end:
                yield list(next(iter([])))

            else:
                yield val

list(_secret())
```

which is easily improvable to

```
def _secret():
    for ind, val in enumerate(infinite_counter()):
        if ind < start:
            continue

        if ind > end:
            break

        yield val

list(_secret())
```

which looks fine to me.

Comment: Amazing what finding the right method can do.  Thanks.  Always nice to find the right solution to something that seems nasty, no matter how you solve it.